# Jest + TypeScript + Babel Unknown option: .0

Tags: typescript, jestjs, babeljs, ts-jest

I've written a single integration test for some of my Fauna DB operations using Jest. Both the source code I'm trying to test (`fauna.ts`) and the test itself (`fauna.test.ts`) are TypeScript files. I've followed [the official Jest "Getting Started" documentation for initial installation, babel setup, and TypeScript support](https://jestjs.io/docs/getting-started).

My test source code:

```
import { describe, expect, test } from '@jest/globals'
import {
  createUser,
  updateUserPaymentTypeByNetlifyID,
  getNetlifyIdByStripeID,
  getStripeIDByNetlifyID,
  getNetlifyIDByEmail,
  deleteUserFauna
} from './fauna'
import PaymentType from '../enums/PaymentType'

const testNetlifyID = 'myNetlifyID'
const testStripeID = 'myStripeID'
const testEmail = 'test@test.com'

describe('createUser function', () => {
  test('creates a user without error', () => {
    expect(createUser(testNetlifyID, testStripeID, testEmail)).not.toThrow()
  })
})

describe('updateUserPaymentTypeByNetlifyID function', () => {
  test("updates a users payment type to 'paypal' without error", () => {
    expect(updateUserPaymentTypeByNetlifyID(testNetlifyID, PaymentType.PAYPAL)).not.toThrow()
  })
})


// more tests...
```

My `babel.config.js` file:

```js
module.exports = {
  presets: [[['@babel/preset-env', { targets: { node: 'current' } }]], '@babel/preset-typescript']
}
```

However, when I issue `npm test` (just calls `jest`), I get the following error:

```
% npm test                            

> functions@1.0.0 test
> jest

 FAIL  src/utils/fauna.test.ts
  ● Test suite failed to run

    [BABEL] /Users/chris/enterprise/wheelscreener/wheelscreener.com/functions/src/utils/fauna.test.ts: Unknown option: .0. Check out https://babeljs.io/docs/en/babel-core/#options for more information about options.

      at transformSync (node_modules/@babel/core/src/transform.ts:66:52)
      at ScriptTransformer.transformSource (node_modules/@jest/transform/build/ScriptTransformer.js:545:31)
      at ScriptTransformer._transformAndBuildScript (node_modules/@jest/transform/build/ScriptTransformer.js:674:40)
      at ScriptTransformer.transform (node_modules/@jest/transform/build/ScriptTransformer.js:726:19)

Test Suites: 1 failed, 1 total
Tests:       0 total
Snapshots:   0 total
Time:        0.468 s
Ran all test suites.
```

Obviously it's an error relating to the babel transformation, but I haven't found any solutions anywhere else, specifically with this error "Unknown option: .0."

Comment: Is that `babel.config.js` correct? Looks like you have too many levels of nesting in the `presets` array - https://babeljs.io/docs/presets#preset-options. Does it work _outside_ the tests?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Babel alone doesn't seem to play well with transformations. [Jest even mentions in their TypeScript docs that there are many caveats to using Babel with TypeScript](https://jestjs.io/docs/getting-started#using-typescript).

In my case, the solution was just installing `ts-jest` with an initial config:

```bash
npx ts-jest config:init
```

after issuing that command, my `npm test` command ran without problems!